# What to do if i don't want to hardcode values in my post request?

Tags: python, django

For now I am just hardcoding values into payload and headers while making post request and it's working fine. But  now I don't want to hardcode those values into payload and make post request .. it should accept the values while making post request dynamically.

Does anyone have any idea?

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
def addtocart(request):
    payload = dict(customer_key='c_5c88d447dde56', hub_id=4, product_id='pr_572359462392e', quantity=1)
    headers = {"content-type":"application/json", "token": "tk_ju9fdm8e", "source":"android"}
    response = requests.post('http://api/cart/update/v2', data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

Comment: Take parameters as input, either from a form or a config file.

Comment: Can u please show me how to do that ?

Comment: So where do you want to store them instead? There are several options, like config files, the database, elsewhere... Decide that, and then get them from there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
def addtocart(request):
    # Query dictionary
    payload = request.data # <QueryDict: {'customer_key': [''], ...}>
    headers = {"content-type":"application/json", "token": "tk_ju9fdm8e", "source":"android"}
    response = requests.post('http://api/cart/update/v2', data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

Comment: because you can't directly loads querydict thats why need to be dumps first before load it.

Comment: That is nonsense.

Comment: Tried what? There is no circumstance in which it makes sense to do this.  If the content-type is json, then `request.data` will already be JSON, in which case *you don't need to do anything at all*. If it is *not* JSON, then `json.dumps()` wouldn't work in the first place.

Comment: got this error if doesn't dumps it first.  `*** TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not QueryDict`. `request.data` in django will return `QueryDict` objects. And it set content-type as `JSON`.

Comment: So in request.data have u hardcoded data there ... or how u are passing that data dynamically?

Comment: no. its not hardcoded. `request.data` is the data you dinamically post to the views.

Comment: ```@csrf_exempt                                             
@api_view(['POST'])       
def addtocart(request):
    payload = dict(customer_key='c_5c88d447dde56', hub_id=4, product_id='pr_572359462392e', quantity=1)
    payload = json.loads(json.dumps(request.data))
    headers = {"content-type":"application/json", "token": "tk_ju9fdm8e", "source":"android"}
    response = requests.post('http://api/cart/update/v2', data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    return HttpResponse(response)```

Comment: Like this you are telling

Comment: your goal is to make values dynamically right?. where is the data like `customer_key`, `hub_id`, `product_id` came from? it's from the request right? @neha

Comment: Thanks it worked for payload can i do the same for headers also  like :         headers = json.loads(json.dumps(request.data))

Comment: @dpht No you can't use `json.loads()`  on `request.data`. `request.data` is already parsed as a `dict`. You are just repeated the parsing.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to make post request by posting headers dynamically ?  Because when I tried to make post request by writing headers = json.loads(json.dumps(request.data)) . It is still asking for access token which is in header.